# Error when I try to make a local translate.

Tags: i18n-l10n

I get this error when I try to make translation:

> Not saved locally due to invalid HTML content.

take a look a my capture, first one shows the text to be saved as the translation, and the second capture shows the error message:

[image: first capture]
[image: second capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you have `<div>` tags in your translation text.

[`locale_string_is_safe()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21includes%21locale.inc/function/locale_string_is_safe/6), the function used to make sure the string provided for translation is safe, has this to say about the allowed tags:

> The allowed tag list is like filter_xss_admin(), but omitting div and img as not needed for translation and likely to cause layout issues (div) or a possible attack vector (img).

So basically you need to remove the `<div>` tags and your translation will work just fine.

If you're interested in the chain of functions called so you can check the logic for yourself, it's as follows:

- [`l10n_client_save_string()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!l10n_client!l10n_client.module/function/l10n_client_save_string/6)
- [`_locale_import_one_string_db()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21includes%21locale.inc/function/_locale_import_one_string_db/6)
- [`locale_string_is_safe()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/drupal%21includes%21locale.inc/function/locale_string_is_safe/6)

Since `locale_string_is_safe()` *does* allow `<span>` tags you might consider using those instead. If you need the element to be block level then you can just use CSS to do that.